# Extract date out of cell with date and time

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a cell `G4` with date and time in a format (Text string):

```
1/29/2020 1:34:24 PM
```

I need to convert it to DATE formatted cell. How to do that?

I have tried to get numbers and convert them to DATE with this formula:

```
=DATE((MID(G4;SEARCH("/";G4)+4;SEARCH("/";G4;SEARCH("/";G4)+1)-SEARCH("/";G4)+2));(MID(G4;SEARCH("/";G4)+1;SEARCH("/";G4;SEARCH("/";G4)+1)-SEARCH("/";G4)-1));(LEFT(G4;FIND("/";G4;1)-1)))
```

So:

1. I am extracting year:

   `=MID(G4;SEARCH("/";G4)+4;SEARCH("/";G4;SEARCH("/";G4)+1)-SEARCH("/";G4)+2)`
2. Month

   `=MID(G4;SEARCH("/";G4)+1;SEARCH("/";G4;SEARCH("/";G4)+1)-SEARCH("/";G4)-1)`
3. Day

   `=LEFT(G4;FIND("/";G4;1)-1)`

I am getting as a result:

```
1.5.2022
```

I need it as it is now, but output should be 29.1.2020 in this case. Later I want to get day difference two that way formatted dates. Is it possible to do it with formula without performing any other cell formatting operations?

---

**EDIT:**

I got it working, the only problem is:

How to extract number (year) after third "/"? My current formula is not correct:

```
=MID(G4;SEARCH("/";G4)+4;SEARCH("/";G4;SEARCH("/";G4)+1)-SEARCH("/";G4)+2)
```

It does not function correct in this case:

```
2/5/2020 12:21:05 PM
```

---

**EDIT:**

I did it this way (I also had to minus G2 - F2, to get days difference):

```
=IFERROR(DAYS(MID(G2;SEARCH("/";G2)+1;SEARCH("/";G2;SEARCH("/";G2)+1)-SEARCH("/";G2)-1)&"."&LEFT(G2;FIND("/";G2;1)-1)&"."&MID(G2;FIND("/";G2;FIND("/";G2)+1)+1;4);MID(F2;SEARCH("/";F2)+1;SEARCH("/";F2;SEARCH("/";F2)+1)-SEARCH("/";F2)-1)&"."&LEFT(F2;FIND("/";F2;1)-1)&"."&MID(F2;FIND("/";F2;FIND("/";F2)+1)+1;4));"")
```

You probably need to replace an order of `day.month.year` and `"."` to `"/"` if you are using different date setting (region). I have one setup, so this seems to work.

Comment: is the date a text string that looks like a date or an actual date/time.  Try changing the number format to `mm/dd/yyyy` or `ShortDate` and see if it changes.

Comment: If it is text because your local settings are `dd/mm/yyyy` then use Text to Columns on the data tab and on the third step select that column and choose date and `mdy` as format.

Comment: Are you able to delimit your date at the space?  You would then be able to texttocolumns the date-only cells

Comment: If it's a text date wouldn't `=DATEVALUE(A1)` work, or just `=A1*1` and then format in the desired date format?

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook the OP's local setting is `dd/mm/yyyy` and the date is coming in as `mm/dd/yyyy` which is causing most of the dates to come in as string and those will not work.

Comment: @ScottCraner Ah, fair enough.  Didn't see that in the post - just looked at the 1/29/2020 and thought must be `mm/dd/yy`. Reading down I didn't spot the desired output of `29.1.2020`.

Comment: the reason you were getting  1.5..2022 is that you were grabbing the month as the day and the day as the month.  Switch those part around and it will work for you.  I made the same mistake initially

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have TEXTJOIN,

```
=TEXTJOIN("/",TRUE,INDEX(FILTERXML("<a>,<b>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TEXT(A1,"dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss"),"/","</b><b>")," ","</b>",1)&"</a>","//b"),N(IF({1},{2,1,3}))))
```

Depending on your version it may need to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]

the reason the second did not work is that Excel actually changed it to a date and a date is a double, not text.  So there are no `/` in the data.  so we need to force back to the incorrect string.

Comment: Thank you for this! I got it working, but I will definitely test your suggestion. I have TEXTJOIN function in the list.

Answer (score 2):

FYI DATES in excel are stored as integers.  They represent the number of days since 1900/01/01 with that date being 1.  TIME is stored as a decimal representing fractions of a day or 24 hours.  0.5 represents noon.  24:00 is not an officially supported time in excel, but will work with some functions.

The DATE Formula is looking for three arguments representing YEAR, MONTH, DAY in that order.

```
DATE(Year, Month, Day)
```

You need to pull the text from your string representing these values.  I find it easiest to pull each one individually in its own cell to ensure the part of the formula is working first then copy and past that part into the DATE formula so the whole calculation in the end can be performed in one cell.

YEAR

To get the year use the following formula:

```
MID(G4,FIND("/",G4,FIND("/",G4)+1)+1,4)
```

MONTH

To get the month use the following formula:

```
LEFT(G4,FIND("/",G4)-1)
```

DAY

To get the day use the following formula:

```
MID(G4,FIND("/",G4)+1,FIND("/",G4,FIND("/",G4)+1)-FIND("/",G4)
```

COMBINED FORMULA

Place the above formulas into the date formula as follows:

```
=DATE(MID(G4,FIND("/",G4,FIND("/",G4)+1)+1,4),LEFT(G4,FIND("/",G4)-1),MID(G4,FIND("/",G4)+1,FIND("/",G4,FIND("/",G4)+1)-FIND("/",G4)-1))
```

Note the only cell reference in the formula is G4.  The results of the formula are not in an Excel Date format.  Change the formatting of your cell to meet your needs.  In your case I would apply a custom cell format of d.m.yyyy

[image: POC]

Answer (score 1):

Those for whom the `TEXTJOIN` function is not available can use this:

```
=DATE(FILTERXML("<DATA><A>" & SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1;"/";"</A><A>");" ";"</A><A>") & "</A></DATA>";"/DATA/A[3]");FILTERXML("<DATA><A>" & SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1;"/";"</A><A>");" ";"</A><A>") & "</A></DATA>";"/DATA/A[1]");FILTERXML("<DATA><A>" & SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1;"/";"</A><A>");" ";"</A><A>") & "</A></DATA>";"/DATA/A[2]"))
```

[image]